# Looking help for openssl version

Tags: tls, openssl

I am using Ubuntu version 12.04 and installed Konqueror(4.8.5) browser on it.
Which version of openssl does it supports.

Comment: How can I detect that which ver of Openssl does it supports ?

Comment: I have a definite feeling that you are asking the wrong question here. Why do you want to know the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The version of openssl (Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools) from the default repositories in Ubuntu 12.04 is 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.33 . This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the internet.

The version of openssl 1.0.2f-2ubuntu1 in Ubuntu 16.04 is only a little bit more recent than the version of openssl in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

```
openssl version
```

or

```
openssl version -a
```

to find out that (and with -a, some other info), as your OpenSSL should be patched regularly to correct vulnerabilities and other flaws, thus any specific answer will be obsolete very quickly.